# Cisco 2960X - Add Stack Member

Tags: cisco, stacking

I need to add another Cisco 2960x stack member to our existing stack and I just want to check that the steps I have in mind are correct:

1. Power up the new switch and check that IOS matches that of the existing stack
2. Copy the config from the existing stack to the new switch
3. Provison the new switch on the existing stack
4. Set stack member number and priority on new switch
5. Physically connect the new switch to the stack using the stacking cable

I've had a look at the Cisco documentation but still have some questions:

1. Is this procedure correct?
2. When configuring the new switch, I will just have to copy the config across and it will use the same IP address when added to the stack?

Have I missed anything obvious?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Check your VTP status and ensure it is in client mode or you might have a really fun day in a prod environment.

Answer (score 1):

> Copy the config from the existing stack to the new switch

You do not copy the config manually between stack members. Just put the same version of IOS on the new member as you use on the rest of the stack, and connect it to the stack.  The config will automatically be pushed to the new member.

> 1. Set stack member number and priority on new switch
> 2. Physically connect the new switch to the stack using the stacking cable

These are reversed. You can't pre-configure the switch member number and priority.  You will change the priority of the stack member after it's connected to the stack, through whichever member is the stack master.